# Ruby: How to use flags like File::RDONLY|File::CREAT with binary mode to open file?

Tags: ruby

In File.open, there seems to be two systems, one set uses "r", "w", "wb", and the other uses "RDONLY", "RDWR". For the second set, I haven't found the flag for "b". Thanks for the help.

"File::BINARY"

uninitialized constant File::BINARY (NameError)

Answer (score 0):

Those flags are called `mode` flags. The mode flag for binary is `BINARY`.

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File/Constants.html

Comment: Is it "File::BINARY" or just "BINARY"? Please check my new edit. Thank you.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Try `::File::BINARY`.

Answer (score 0):

`File::BINARY`, listed in [File constants](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File/Constants.html).

**EDIT:** On my system, it works:

```
$ ruby -e "puts File::BINARY"
0
```

(it doesn't do much, but it's there). Note this:

> If the underlying platform doesn't define a constant the corresponding Ruby constant is not defined.

So you might be getting interference from your OS? Or maybe you misspelled it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in any ruby program:

```
p File::RDONLY
p File::CREAT
p File::BINARY
```

I get:

```
--output:--
0
512
1.rb:3: uninitialized constant File::BINARY (NameError)
```

Or, to see which constants File::Constants actually defines on your system, you can do this:

```
File::Constants.constants.sort.each do |const|
  puts "#{const} = #{File::Constants.const_get(const)}"
end
```

I get this:

```
APPEND = 8
CREAT = 512
EXCL = 2048
FNM_CASEFOLD = 8
FNM_DOTMATCH = 4
FNM_NOESCAPE = 1
FNM_PATHNAME = 2
FNM_SYSCASE = 0
LOCK_EX = 2
LOCK_NB = 4
LOCK_SH = 1
LOCK_UN = 8
NOCTTY = 131072
NONBLOCK = 4
RDONLY = 0
RDWR = 2
SYNC = 128
TRUNC = 1024
WRONLY = 1
```

No BINARY for me(OSX 10.6.8).